# How to pass JSON string from Controller action to View and load as parameter for JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        function mapInit(data) {
            var map;

            alert(data);

            map = new L.Map('map', { zoom: 8, layers: [OSM] });

            var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(arr);
        }

        mapInit('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');

    });
```

In the controller action it returns a json string constructed manually which I need to pass to the view in the jQuery function to render the map.

However when the string is passed as model it loses its formatting by the string is not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the view to accept a `string` as the model, then pass it in your `View()` result. e.g.

```
@model String
```

Inserted at the top of the view, then:

```
return View(tt);
```

Within the action.

Then, within the view dump that string so JavaScript can continue on:

```
@* ... *@
mapInit('@Html.Raw(Model)')
@* ... *@
```

Though you should probably create a model, populate it in the controller, hand it off tot he view, then use something like Newtonsoft's JSON library and output it to the page.

Comment: Brad I changed the line return View(tt) to return View((object)tt) as it was giving an error. It is still not rendering the map. Is there another way of doing this.

Comment: Look at the source of the rendered page--does it look correct (syntactically)?

Comment: Brad I have changed the code above - this was because the previous controller action was not formatting the JSON string correctly. hence i have manually done it. but still does not render. the alert in the jquery function shows the string is not complete and thus is not rendered. this line mapInit('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'); is not passing the json correctly to the function

Comment: can you update your answer with that is being generated by the razor view? (just the `mapInit(...)` portion)

Comment: @user2906420: Noo many quotes I believe. try using `mapInit(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));` (and if razor complains, use `@Html.Raw("mapInit(" + Json.Encode(Model) + ")")` instead)

Comment: Brad thanks alot, it works. However I feel I have manually created the json string which is not a good way - how else can you create a json string from a datatable. thanks